# Sum of repeated roots

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, summation

I am interested in the value of the following sum:

$$\sum_{j=2}^{\sqrt{n}}n^{1/j}$$

where $n$ is an arbitrary positive integer.

It is quite obvious that the value of the sum is less than $n$.

Does anyone know the exact value of this sum?  If not, I need a good lower bound, something like $c \cdot n$ if possible (for a constant $c$).

Comment: You are right, let's start with $j=2$ :-)

Comment: Do you mean $\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor$ ?

Comment: Yes, also right. Or let us assume that $\sqrt{n}$ is a positive integer.

Comment: What is $j$ in your solution?

Comment: a simple lower bound is just $(\sqrt n-1)n^{1/\sqrt n}$

Comment: @Masacroso: Unfortunately, that only gives a lower bound of $c\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Currently I think that my assumptions is wrong and $c \cdot n$ is not a lower bound.

Comment: @Jannik: I don't think the sum is $\gg n$ either. In fact, I think the correct bound is $\sqrt{n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Approximating the sum by an integral, you have

$$\sum_{j=2}^{\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor}n^{1/j}\approx \sqrt n\,n^{1/\sqrt n}-\log(n)\,\text{Ei}\left(\frac{\log n}{\sqrt n}\right)+C$$

Notice that the first term is $\sqrt n$, and the next ones tend to $1$ pretty slowly. There are $\sqrt n$ of them, which explains that the behavior is above $\sqrt n$.

Comment: Yes, a good hint, thank you. I still try to interpret the result-

Comment: @Jannik: typo, sorry. The asymptotic behavior seems to be a little above the square root.

Comment: Mathematica gives $\ \sqrt{n}\ n^{1/\sqrt{n}} - 2\sqrt{n} +\log(n)(\textrm{Ei}(\log(n)/2) - \textrm{Ei}(\log(n)/\sqrt{n}))$